# How to set the compatible library in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, android-studio, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I know this has been asked before, but can not seem to find the answer in previous questions, so here goes.

I have created a project in Unity and exported it to Android Studio. I have set min API Level to 4.4 KitKat (API Level 19).

I have added:  in the main manifest file. When building I get this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:UniWebView:] /Users/myname/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/97563e885486a53e4f6658e98b58f094/jetified-UniWebView/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.onevcat.uniwebview" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

How do i set the compatible library to minSdk 19? It needs to be 19 and not 21 due to the fact that if I release the update with 21 almost 20% of my users will be unable to play the game :-/

```
Units not compatible with API level 21+ = 2054 (19%)
```

Actually... A side question... Should I be afraid of upgrading API in term of loosing users? I have a version using API level 21 which is ready to be released.

If I should be carefull with this, how do I solve initial issue?

hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 4 options:

1. Increase you project's minSdk to 21 and lose users
2. Add `tools:overrideLibrary="com.onevcat.uniwebview"` to your manifests's application tag, which will probably lead to runtime crashes for your API 19 users (please test the whole thing heavily if you choose this option!!!)
3. Throw away the library and find another one. Or write your own solution
4. Fork the library (in case it's open sourced) and try to decrease its minSdk to 19

If I were you, I'd go with option 3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure how to approach solution #3. Any guides or solutions for this? I might also in regards to solution #1 still losse users since last minSDK level was 16+ :-/